# Play random sound clip on collision (Unity)

Tags: c#, audio, random, unity-game-engine, collision

I have 4 sound files that are landing noises i want the player to make when colliding with the ground, at the moment no sound is playing. New to C# and programming need a bit of help please.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Bhop : MonoBehaviour{

public AudioClip[] list;
AudioSource audio;
CharacterController characterController;
int number;

void Start () 
{
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    //Loading the items into the array
    list =  new AudioClip[]
    {
        (AudioClip)Resources.Load("Sound/jumplanding1.wav"),
        (AudioClip)Resources.Load("Sound/jumplanding2.wav"), 
        (AudioClip)Resources.Load("Sound/jumplanding3.wav"), 
        (AudioClip)Resources.Load("Sound/jumplanding4.wav")
    };
}

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    int number;
    number = Random.Range(0, list.Length);


    if (col.gameObject.name == "Sound") 
    {
        audio.PlayOneShot(list[number], 0.5f);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you debug on a collision that should make a sound, is `col.gameObject.name == "Sound"` equating to true?

Comment: Might also doublecheck if the sound resources in the `Resources/Sound` folder. To make it sure, you can drag and drop each clip into the list in the inspector instead of load them on `Start()`.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the collision handler is getting called? Try to output something there. If that works then try to put the "PlayOnShot" at the end of the Start method and see if the sound plays just to eliminate any other variables. Let us know what the results are.

Answer (score 1):

Here Mate

Instructions:
1 - attach this to any  gameobject
2 - place the gameobject with the AudioSource component to mySource
3 - Lets say you have 3 audio clips you want to use, set both Range Scan and My Audio Elements to 3
4 -  add your 3 clips as elements
5 - Enable Debug to get a list of the clips on the console  but  they also show on the editor as you play the game

Tips: this is on enable, so everytime this object is enable its gonna run a new range and assign the clip, Hope it helps took me  about 5 minutes, if this helps you please consider following my facebook dev group [HERE](https://www.facebook.com/tiagoserrafanspage/)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class randomSound : MonoBehaviour {


    public AudioSource mySource;
    public int rangeScan;
    public AudioClip[] myAudio;
    public int toPlay;
    public bool debugging;

    void OnEnable () {
        toPlay = Random.Range(0,rangeScan);
        if (debugging) {
            foreach (AudioClip value in myAudio) {
                print (value);
            }
        }
        mySource.PlayOneShot(myAudio[toPlay], 0.9F);
        mySource.Play ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've attached the script to the GameObject before you added the `[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]` line, you most likely do not have an [Audio Source](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html) component for your GameObject (check your Inspector). If that is the case you can either:

- manually add an **Audio Source** component in the Inspector, or
- delete and then re-attach the script to the GameObject, which will automatically add the **Audio Source** component with it. If you are using a public `AudioClip` variable for your audio file (OP is not), remember to drag and drop the sound asset into the public variable of the script once again (it cleared with script re-attachment).

Answer (score -2):

```
Audio.PlayOneShot(AudioClip[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,AudioClip.Length)], 0.8f);
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation for this?